# How do I specify a zone offset in a DateTimeFormatterBuilder without using a pattern?

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to parse the following timestamp into a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
Sun Jan 20 16:08:59 +0000 2019
```

I like to avoid using patterns defined in strings where I can because I often forget what the characters stand for ("huh, is 'M' month of year, or minute of hour...?")

In the following example, how can I get rid of the pattern "xxxx", which represents a zone offset? I tried [`appendOffsetId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffsetId--) but it uses a different pattern, so parsing fails.

Is there a better way?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendText(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, TextStyle.SHORT)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, TextStyle.SHORT)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1, 2, SignStyle.NEVER)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendPattern("xxxx")   // How do I change this?
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
    .toFormatter();

System.out.println(
    ZonedDateTime.parse("Sun Jan 20 16:08:59 +0000 2019", formatter)
);
```

Comment: I take it you also do not consider `.appendOffset("+HHMM", "????")` acceptable?  Note that the first argument is not a DateFormatter pattern and is [restricted to nine permissible values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: @VGR It's pretty good. Certainly better than what I have now so you should definitely post it as an answer (though you'd want a better second argument). If the method only takes 9 arguments, why didn't they define an enum, I wonder? [Two hard things](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html) ?

Comment: I have to admit, my first thought was that it should be an enum as well.  Maybe it was believed that patterns are historically better understood by developers.  Or maybe it’s because the enum constant names were attempted and were just too awkward (`HOUR_OPTIONAL_MINUTE_NO_COLON`, `HOUR_MINUTE_OPTIONAL_SECOND_WITH_COLON`, etc.).

Comment: They ought to have learned: patterns are error-prone! I suspect that they thought the pattern approach was more extensible in case they wanted to add further patterns later. Also @VGR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [appendOffset](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) rather than appendOffsetId.  The first argument is a pattern, but not a DateTimeFormatter pattern;  in fact it is limited to 22 possible String values:

```
.appendOffset("+HHMM", "????")
```

Comment: From Java 9 it’s 22 possible formats. Still rather limited.